# USB storage device requires unplugging and re-plugging to make it work after reboot

Tags: mount, filesystem, usb-drive, bios, input-devices

When I do `lsblk` or `blkid` it just does not show up until I go and physically unplug/re-plug the USB.

I've tried the disabling Auto-suspend method so it's not that, not sure what's going on. Is it the OS itself, or possibly my BIOS settings?